# Segmentation fault (core dumped) error when running my program

Tags: c

so i am supposed to create a program that analyzes said text file and when i first ran it, i didn't have the text file created, but once i created it and tried to run the program i got a seg fault error and now i don't know how to fix it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
 
#define FILENAME "poems.txt"
 
int getWords(int maxWord, char words[][maxWord], FILE*);

int countLetters(char str_letter[]);

int countLowerCase(char str_lower[]);

int countVowels(char str_vowel[]);
 
int main()
{
    int maxWord=50;
    int numWord=0;
    char words[numWord][maxWord];
    char str_letter[75];
    char str_lower[75];
    char str_vowel[75];
    FILE* fp;
    int numLetter;
    int numLower;
    int numVowel;
 
    fp=fopen(FILENAME, "r");
    if(fp==NULL) {
        printf ("poems.txt could not be found!\n");
    }
    else {
        getWords(maxWord, words, fp);
        countLetters(str_letter);
        countLowerCase(str_lower);
        countVowels(str_vowel);
 
        printf ("There are %d letters in your file.\n", numLetter);
        printf ("There are %d lower case letters in your file.\n", numLower);
        printf ("There are %d vowels in your file.\n", numVowel);
 
        fclose(fp);
    }
 
    return 0;
}
 
int getWords(int maxWord, char words[][maxWord], FILE* inFILE)
{
    int numWord=0;
    char poem;
 
    while(fscanf(inFILE, "%s", &poem)==1){
        words[numWord][maxWord]=poem;
        numWord++;
    }
    numWord++;
 
    return numWord;
}
 
int countLetters(char str_letter[])
{

    int numLetter=0;    
 
    for(int i=0; i<strlen(str_letter); i++) {
        if((str_letter[i]>'a' && str_letter[i]<'z')||(str_letter[i]>'A' && str_letter[i]<'Z'));
            numLetter++;
    }
 
    return numLetter;
}
 
int countLowerCase(char str_lower[])
{
    int numLower=0;
 
    for(int i=0; i<strlen(str_lower); i++) {
        if(str_lower[i]>'a' && str_lower[i]<'z');
            numLower++;
    }
 
    return numLower;
}
 
int countVowels(char str_vowel[])
{

    int numVowel=0;
 
    for(int i=0; i<strlen(str_vowel); i++) {
        if(str_vowel[i]=='a'||str_vowel[i]=='e'||str_vowel[i]=='i'||str_vowel[i]=='o'||str_vowel[i]=='u')
        {
            numVowel++;
        }
 
        else if(str_vowel[i]=='A'||str_vowel[i]=='E'||str_vowel[i]=='I'||str_vowel[i]=='O'||str_vowel[i]=='U')
        {
            numVowel++;
        }
    }
 
    return numVowel;
}
```

Comment: try to make your code shorter...and only provide the portion giving you error...

Comment: at least one problem, the format specifier `"%s"` in `while(fscanf(inFILE, "%s", &poem)` expects a string, but you give it a `char`. Probably want to change that to `"%c"`.

Answer (score 0):

You are making so many mistakes on your code, so i need to ask, you understands how dynamic memory allocation and pointers works in C? Is not like other languajes, you need to allocate memory before you access to them.

If you dont have a text file, your code works and the output is:

```
poems.txt could not be found!
```

So up to here everithings seems to work fine, but it doesn't.

Lets go to the line where you declare:

```
int maxWord=50;
int numWord=0;
char words[numWord][maxWord];
```

Here you are saying "SAVE ME AN ARRAY OF 0 POSITIONS AS COLUMNS AND 50 POSITIONS OF ROWS" so when you execute the following code in the function getWords, your code breaks.

```
while(fscanf(inFILE, "%s", &poem)==1){
    words[numWord][maxWord]=poem;
    numWord++;
}
```

Because the position:

```
words[1][maxWord]
```

isn't allocated.

You got two ways of allocate memory in C as far as i know, dynamic and static memory allocation.

I believe you came from learning another languaje like python or javascript where this types of things "works" but not in C.

If you want to solve this problems take a look to dynamic memory allocation and how C pointers works, you can make your code unstopable!